# Is there a way to change the color of an icon inside preference headers?

Tags: java, android

I've added some icons (as SVGs) to my preference header file and I want to change the color of them with Java (my app is themeable and I can't find any other way to change the icon color according to the theme).

I've already tried changing the color of the icon in a similar way to buttons, etc... I can't change the color with the "app:tint" attribute either and it dosen't change with the theme no matter what I do.

Here is the preference header code. I want to change the color of "ic_round_settings".

```
<header
     android:fragment="com.appname.settings.fragment.GeneralSettingsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_round_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings_general"
        android:summary="@string/settings_general_explain" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found one way of doing it. If you add an attr attribute to the preference header like this:

```
<header
        android:fragment="com.appname.settings.fragment.GeneralSettingsFragment"
        android:icon="?attr/ic_round_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings_general"
        android:summary="@string/settings_general_explain" />
```

and add that attribute to the attr.xml file in the values folder:

```
<attr name="ic_round_settings" format="reference"/>
```

And add that into the theme classes in styles.xml with a light and dark version of the icon, the theme will change:

```
<style name="Theme.BaseLightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="ic_round_settings">@drawable/ic_round_settings_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.BaseDarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="ic_round_settings">@drawable/ic_round_settings_light</item>
</style>
```

With this in the SVG icon file, changing the color from #000000 to #ffffff in the light SVG icon copy:

```
<path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData=""/>
```

Edit: This won't work on Android 4.4 and below - the icons won't appear at all

Comment: This doesn't work on Android 5.0 and below because how the app bulding process works

Comment: @SomerandomITboy It seems to work on Android 5.0 but the app dosen't launch at all on 4.4 and below.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy Actually, the crash was due to another drawable I had in my app. On 4.4 and below they just don't seem to appear which is fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that behaviour use the reference to the color in the XML like so

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:tint="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/chat_send_text"
                android:drawableTint="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_paper_plane"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also, when working with the activities **make sure you set the theme before using `setContentView(R.layout_your_layout_file)` ** or else you'll have to call `recreate()` when you set the theme dynamically.

#### Example

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(whatever_theme_you_want_to_use)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cool)
    // Further view initialization
}
```

The drawback is that you would have to explicitly `setTheme` in all of your activities since Android doesn't give developers an easier way to change the theme app-wide.

Comment: You can also use this strategy to set the color attribute of any other XML element in Android